# Can't retrieve an id through swfupload

Tags: php, javascript, swfupload

I'm having trouble retrieving an echoed ajax response through SWFupload.  Upon uploading a file, my account.php?action=uploadphotographs echos the number 37, the text field hidFileId should then be updated with this data.  I'm not sure if the file is ever properly being submitted.  Is there something wrong with my code?

Heres a link to my SWFUpload code: http://pastie.org/962656

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: So I tried writing to a text file from with in my 'uploadphotographs' action, but nothing happens.  So my upload page is never getting called, if this helps at all.

EDIT: Also, my file progress is not updating either

SOLUTION:  Ok, I sort of figured out what's going on... it has something to do with my handlers.js, the code up at the top that controls the onmouseover and onmouseout for btnSubmit.  When I take this code out, the file is successfully uploaded... any ideas why this would break the script?

Comment: What does the account.php look like. I'm not seeing it in the pastie.

Comment: http://pastie.org/962728

Comment: Another note:  the fileprogress handler never seems to get called upon hitting submit, it just instantly goes to my form action page

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, there is a problem in the *handlers.js* file, a syntax error would be the most likely cause. Modern browsers are able to tell you if there is an error in your scripts, and point out the line the problem occurs on (Firefox and Chrome are good at this). And since it works once you take out the file in question, there would have to be something wrong with it.

So I'd start by checking the file for any errors.